# How to fetch column name which is not in JSON but still it is an array element that i have received using PHP in android

Tags: java, php, android, json

How can a column name, which is not in JSON but still it is an array element that I have received using PHP in android, be fetched?
This is my PHP file:

```
   {
        "items": [
        {
          "v_id": "1",
          "v_name": "Hotel Girija",
          "v_address": "Vijayanagar Colony, Municipal Colony, Pune,         Maharashtra 411030",
          "v_avg_rating": "3",
          "v_image": "http://i1.walesonline.co.uk/whats-on/food-drink-news/article7978981.ece/ALTERNATES/s615/MAin.jpg",
          "v_contact1": "8456217412"
        },
        {
          "v_id": "4",
          "v_name": "Pataleshwar hotel",
          "v_address": "Some addresss again",
          "v_avg_rating": "5",
          "v_image": "https://www.whatsuplife.in/gurgaon/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Chaat-Chowk.jpg",
          "v_contact1": "5452232554"
        }
      ],
      "sub_image": "http://www.asiansinamerica.org/wp- content/uploads/2016/08/Asian-and-Chinese-Food.jpg",
      "success": 1
    }
```

I have to get all values of key *items* using this :

```
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject(items);
    JSONArray arr = root.getJSONArray("items");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
        path = "" + obj.optString("v_image");
        // path = "http://" + path.replaceAll("\\s+", "%20");
        al_subcatdetl_id.add("" + obj.optString("v_id"));
        al_subcatdetl_name.add("" + obj.optString("v_name"));
        al_subcatdetl_addr.add("" + obj.optString("v_address"));
        al_subcatdetl_img.add("" + path);
        al_subcatdetl_rating.add("" + obj.optString("v_avg_rating"));

       ///al_subject_img.add(obj.getString("sub_image"));
    }
```

But i don't have any idea how to fetch *sub_image*, which is outside of *items*. How can this be achieved?

Comment: of which type is `JSONObject`? jackson or anyone else? can you just paste the import statement

Comment: JSONObject subImage = root.getJSONObject("sub_image");

Comment: import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: `sub_image` is a string. So, you get it as 
`String subImage = root.getString("sub_image");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these case you can directly get string from JSONObject

```
try {    
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(items);
String  subimage = root.getString("sub_image");
} catch(Exception ex){

}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, i got value of sub_image using this... :)

Comment: @Abhijeet you should accept the answer if you got the solution, encourage the person who wrote the answer for you.